# The set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^3=y^2 \}$ is not a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Prove that the set $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^3=y^2 \}$ is not a submanifold.
This is the exercise from the book and I cannot understand why the chart $\phi :S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{y}$ doesn't work.

Comment: Is the map differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Are you talking about differentiable manifolds, smooth manifolds, or general topological manifolds?

Comment: @egreg Do you talk about the map $f\colon\boldsymbol{R}^2\to\boldsymbol{R}$ defined by $f(x,y):=x^3-y^2$?  Clearly $f$ is analytic and $S=f^{-1}(0)$.  We know that $S$ is Neil's parabola, it may be parametrized by $t\mapsto(t^2,t^3)$, which is analytic, too. So the answer to your question is: “Yes.”

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was talking of $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Graphs of smooth functions are submanifolds. If you graph $x^3 = y^2$ you will notice that the point $(0,0)$ is most likely the problem. This also explains why your function is not a chart.

Comment: Graphs of smooth functions are submanifolds.  $S$ is not a smooth function at $(0,0)$?  But not all submanifolds are graphs of smooth functions; it seems like more needs to be said.

Comment: Gaffney: I will expand the answer.